# Hyper-V DDA: Enable PnpDevice from Windows RE

Tags: windows, windows-10, hyper-v

I was trying to use `Hyper-V` `DDA` for my `GPU` and ran the following `script` from `microsoft.com`. See `script` at bottom of page: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/deploy/deploying-graphics-devices-using-dda

After running it, it seems it disabled the `device` for my host PC resulting in the screen freezing after `Windows` loads.

I assume this is because of the following lines:

`Disable-PnpDevice  -InstanceId $gpudevs[0].InstanceId`

and possibly

`Dismount-VMHostAssignableDevice -force -LocationPath $locationPath`

Is there a way to reverse this using the `Windows` recovery? Id est, in `CMD.EXE`. Safe-mode seems to have the same issue.